# Is FQL giving wrong typage?

Tags: facebook, types, facebook-fql

I am starting with *FQL*, and I am having some issues with columns' type being not as expected.

For example, [docs of table *friend*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) says that `uid2` is an **int**, but I receive **strings** when I lookup this table:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
```

that gives me:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid2": "100004469923697"
    }
  ]
}
```

and with *photo* table too, when I expect a **string** at `owner`:

```
SELECT owner FROM photo WHERE owner=me()
```

...I receive an **int**:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "owner": 100004536330032
    }
  ]
}
```

Is that right?

**Edit:** Not parsed data, raw, as received from [source](https://graph.facebook.com/fql) and [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that json is loosely typed, and depending on the parser used to generate the json objects numbers can be arbitrarily typed as strings or integers.

According to [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example), "One disadvantage is that the number 25 is reflected as a number, but may have been a string as base type in a database." No reference is given, and a quick Google didn't shed any light on this.

You'll just have to be aware that when getting json data from Facebook, the type received may not always be the type expected.

Comment: I agree, and understand what is probably causing this.
However, if docs explicit says the type, it should guarantee this.

I see this issue as a fail, documenting or implementing, and can't be accepted as right, or nothing to do about it.

Comment: If it's that important to you, file a bug report. Also, if you need guarantees that the API documentation always is consistent and the data you receive is always what you expect, I'd **strongly** suggest you avoid the Facebook API.

Comment: Done, bug reported.
Interested people, [**subscribe** here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/452210561495837)!